# jTree node selection

Tags: java, swing, jtree, cardlayout

I have Main `JFrame` with `jTree` and displayPanel, also FirstPanel and SecondPanel. By clicking `jTree` nodes will be selected each `jPanels`.

Here is code:

```
package demo;

import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeSelectionModel;

public class Main extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Main
     */
    public Main() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        treePanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTree1 = new javax.swing.JTree();
        displayPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        firstPanel = new demo.FirstPanel();
        secondPanel = new demo.SecondPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode treeNode1 = new javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode("Main");
        javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode treeNode2 = new javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode("Unit");
        javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode treeNode3 = new javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode("time");
        treeNode2.add(treeNode3);
        treeNode3 = new javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode("velocity");
        treeNode2.add(treeNode3);
        treeNode1.add(treeNode2);
        jTree1.setModel(new javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel(treeNode1));
        jTree1.addTreeSelectionListener(new javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener() {
            public void valueChanged(javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent evt) {
                jTree1ValueChanged(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTree1);

        treePanel.add(jScrollPane1);

        getContentPane().add(treePanel, java.awt.BorderLayout.WEST);

        displayPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.CardLayout());
        displayPanel.add(firstPanel, "first");
        displayPanel.add(secondPanel, "second");

        getContentPane().add(displayPanel, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jTree1ValueChanged(javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent evt) {                                    
         String node = evt.getNewLeadSelectionPath().getLastPathComponent().toString();
         if (node == null)
         return;
    if( node.equals("time") ) {
        displayPanel.add(firstPanel);
    } else if( node.equals("velocity") ) {
       displayPanel.add(secondPanel);
    }

    }                                   

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Main().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel displayPanel;
    private demo.FirstPanel firstPanel;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTree jTree1;
    private demo.SecondPanel secondPanel;
    private javax.swing.JPanel treePanel;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Problem is there:

```
private void jTree1ValueChanged(javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent evt) {                                    
         String node = evt.getNewLeadSelectionPath().getLastPathComponent().toString();
         if (node == null)
         return;
    **if( node.equals("time") ) {
        displayPanel.add(firstPanel);
    } else if( node.equals("velocity") ) {
       displayPanel.add(secondPanel);**
    }
```

When I am clicking **time node** it shows me **secondPanel**, when clicking **velocity node** it shows me **firstPanel**. I don't know how to switch them.
Question is: how to make that **time node** shows **firstPanel**, **velocity node** shows **secondPanel**?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem:

```
displayPanel.add(firstPanel);
...
displayPanel.add(secondPanel);
```

You are trying to add components to an already displayed container and component's hierarchy is [invalidated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add-java.awt.Component-). You need to revalidate the components hierarchy when adding/removing components dynamically:

```
displayPanel.add(firstPanel);
displayPanel.revalidate(); // calls the layout manager
displayPanel.repaint(); // repaints the component
```

However IMHO this is a great use case for [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) (link to tutorial). I'd suggest you this approach:

1. Have a `cardPanel` with `CardLayout` placed in the area where you want your panels show up.
2. Add all your panels (`firstPanel`, `secondPanel`, ...) to this `cardPanel` using appropriate constraints (i.e.: `time` and `velocity`.
3. On tree selection change, switch the panels using `CardLayout` method [show(cardPanel, constraint)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html#show-java.awt.Container-java.lang.String-), where `constraint` is the constraint used to add the panel to the `cardPanel`.

Comment: What advice did you follow and what doesn't work? @Dirak

Comment: I am sorry,  I was misunderstood. Your method works perfect. Thank you very much for detailed and nice explanation. Many thanks for your time. @dic19